# Application wide shell login

Tags: sapui5

I added to my view the shell component:

[image]

that looks as follow:

[image]

My question, how shell component application wide? Every views should own the shell component.

Comment: Are you using routing?

Comment: Yes I do and I solve my problem on App.view.xml.